# How to map key to multiple values to dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, series

I have a df column that looks like this:

```
col1
Non Profit
Other-501c3
501c3
Sole Proprietor
```

How can I create a dictionary object or mapping layer(open to all suggestions) where I can pass any value if it matches criteria and changes to the key value?

For example if the value is `Other-501c3` then change it to `non-profit`.

Examples (everything after the equal sign needs to change to the value before equal sign):

```
1. non-profit = (Non Profit, Other-501c3, 501c3,NON-Profit, Not-for-profit).

2. Sole Proprietor = (Sole Proprietor,Sole Proprietorship)
```

The solution should be scalable I can add in more 'key value' pairs

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create dictionaries from `key`s, merge them and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
L1 = ['Non Profit', 'Other-501c3', '501c3','NON-Profit', 'Not-for-profit']
d1 = dict.fromkeys(L1, 'non-profit')

L2 = ['Sole Proprietor','Sole Proprietorship']
d2 = dict.fromkeys(L2, 'Sole Proprietor')

d = {**d1, **d2}
print (d)
{'Non Profit': 'non-profit', 
 'Other-501c3': 'non-profit', 
 '501c3': 'non-profit',
 'NON-Profit': 'non-profit', 
 'Not-for-profit': 'non-profit', 
 'Sole Proprietor': 'Sole Proprietor',
 'Sole Proprietorship': 'Sole Proprietor'}

df['new'] = df['col1'].map(d)
print (df)
              col1              new
0       Non Profit       non-profit
1      Other-501c3       non-profit
2            501c3       non-profit
3  Sole Proprietor  Sole Proprietor
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar solution to [@jezrael's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52761490/9209546), but instead of creating a new dictionary you can use [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap

# dataframe setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Non Profit', 'Other-501c3', '501c3', 'Sole Proprietor']})

# create ChainMap
L1 = ['Non Profit', 'Other-501c3', '501c3','NON-Profit', 'Not-for-profit']
L2 = ['Sole Proprietor','Sole Proprietorship']
d = ChainMap(dict.fromkeys(L1, 'non-profit'), dict.fromkeys(L2, 'Sole Proprietor'))

# map values
df['new'] = df['col1'].map(d.get)

print(df)

              col1              new
0       Non Profit       non-profit
1      Other-501c3       non-profit
2            501c3       non-profit
3  Sole Proprietor  Sole Proprietor
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to ChainMap vs using `|` between the dictionaries? E.g, `d = dict.fromkeys(L1, 'non-profit') | dict.fromkeys(L2, 'Sole Proprietor')` (available since 3.9) What I can see is that if there are overlapping keys, ChainMap uses the key from the first dictionary, while `|` uses the key from the second.